# Неизвестная причина многократной работы скрипта.

Tags: php

Вот это да... Ввел переменную $_SESSION['count'] и прописал в index.php:

```
echo $_SESSION['count']++
```

Так вот, при каждом обновлении страницы на локальном сервере  эта переменная увеличивается сразу на 2 единицы, а на хостинге - на 3, т.е. скрипт работает по столько же раз. Столько же раз подключаются и остальные модули (classes.php,футер, хэдэр...)

В .htaccess прописано :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Уважаемые программисты, получается страница сайта загружается по 2-3 раза одновременно или скрипт на сервере работает столько же раз, а вывод в браузер однократный. Я ничего не могу понять.

Удалил файл .htaccess - $_SESSION как и положено увеличивается на единицу...

**UPDATE** Понятно, .htaccess действует на все папки в директории - из-за этого многократное выполнение index.php. Тогда **вопрос 2** - как запретить htaccess такое поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я читал, что подобное было у одного мужика. У него был yandexbar. Так вот он каждый раз за ним заходил на страницу. У Вас скорее всего ещё и favicon.ico запрашивается. А правила для несуществующих файлов перенаправляют их все в index.php.

Итак:

- добавьте favicon.ico в корень и проверьте эту гипотезу.
- используйте "чистый браузер" без дополнительных плугинов.
- научитесь делать запросы с помощью curl.
- научитесь смотреть логи апача. Там бывают подсказки.

Comment: Да убрал я все с index.php, написал - 

echo SESSION['count']++ 

и все. Все равно по два раза скрипт пробегает.

Comment: @KoVadim, wtf? Спасибо... Не понял, при чем здесь favicon.ico? Да, я создал пустой файл favicon.ico и, по-моему, все заработало. Что за беспредел творится в ИТ-сфере? Почему НИГДЕ об этом не сказано????

Comment: Браузер запрашивает его, что бы отобразить иконку для сайта. Это как бы известно.

Comment: @KoVadim, Я не знал, что браузер его в обязательном порядке запрашивает. Нигде об этом и слова не сказано. Я думал, favicon - это по желанию разработчика.